# Save my older application SQLITE based database while installing the newer version in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I made an application in which I save few information in my SQLite database. 
As we know that SQLite database resides in the internal memory of the device and its created while app installation and deleted when we remove the respective application.

I am releasing a new version of the application, so when I delete my older version to install the newer version I lost the complete information which I had saved in the older version.

My query is can i retrieve the data from the older version from its SQLite database somehow so that, it can be used and maintained in the newer version.

Please suggest me so that my users must not lost their old data.

Comment: Last time I checked, an update doesn't delete data, it just replaces the application files.

Answer (score 3):

If the user updates the application then the database will remain intact.  Uninstalling the old version and re-installing the new version will cause the database to be deleted.

Comment: Please suggest me, what process and logic i must implement, so that user can update their application from newer version without deleting the older version.

Comment: The user doesn't do anything but hit the "Update" button from the Google Play app.  It then downloads and installs the new version (replacing program files but leaving all data and settings intact).  You seem to be thinking in PC Desktop terms and Android doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment, I really don't think you need to worry about it.

However, if you want to back up and restore your database, the following methods will send it to the SD Card and then read it back in (overwriting what was previously there in each case):

```
public void backup() {
    try {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File outputFile = new File(sdcard,
                "yourDB.bak");

        if (!outputFile.exists()) 
             outputFile.createNewFile(); 

        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File inputFile = new File(data,
                "data/your.package.name/databases/yourDB.sqlite");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Error("Copying Failed");
    }
}

public void restore() {
    try {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File inputFile = new File(sdcard,
                "yourDB.bak");

        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File outputFile = new File(data,
                "data/your.package.name/databases/yourDB.sqlite");

        if (!outputFile.exists()) 
             outputFile.createNewFile(); 

        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Error("Copying Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Barak, thanks for reply for my query instantly. The code which you have provided is very useful but it is, if I implemented that in my older version. I can' t do that now, as users already using my app. :(

Comment: I see.  Well, if it is merely an update, no need to worry, the database won't be deleted.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can I prepare my app, so that user can update their older version from newer version.

Comment: I don't understand... you want both version on the device at once?  Not possible.  You'd have to change the package name, and then it wouldn't be an update, it would be a new app, and it could not access the other apps data.

Comment: Hello Barak, I apologies it was just lack of experience. the process was new for me. I got to know about the update process of any older version of the application from its newer version.
And the good thing is that we don't have to delete our older application as we are updating the app not installing the new application.
Thanx alot for guiding me, I have done with my new concepts and task.